# How can used x^y instead of pow(x,y) in code in android studio?

Tags: math, pow

For parametric programming, I need to use (for example : (x^3 + y^2)^(x + y) )instead of (pow(x,3) + pow
(y,2) ,... in coding in Android Studio. Can anyone make a suggestion for this?

Comment: What do you mean, you *need* to write `^` instead of `pow`?

Comment: in C++ you can overload `^` operator with your `pow` function ...

Comment: Use `^` in Android just like you also use any  `+` or `*` or `=` etc in some math equation. It is an **operator** found in most programming languages (with Math functions).

Comment: What about android studio. In android studio in common way I can not use ^ operation instead of math.pow

Comment: Android studio is IDE, your question depends on used language. In C/C++ languages (Which that IDE supports) the `^` is binary operator representing bitwise binary XOR (and `^^` is boolean XOR) You can overload the operator function for any of your datatype so you can create your own class representing int or what ever you need and create its own class member operator: `T operator ^ (const T &x){ return pow(*this,x); }` where `T` is your datatype class.. outside class it would look like `T operator ^ (const T &x,const T &y){ return pow(x,y); }`